# Setting loglevel of pgadmin4 in docker container using docker compose v2

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I simply want to increase the loglevel for my pgadmin4 service inside my docker-compose.yaml file. But everything I've tried so far doesn't seem to work. BTW, I have Docker Compose version `v2.12.1`

Here is a minimal code sample:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL=${PGADMIN_CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL}
    depends_on:
      - db
#    logging:
#      driver: none

volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

**.env**

```
DB_HOST=db
DB_NAME=db_name
DB_USER=db_user
DB_PASS=db_pass
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=db_user@example.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=db_pass
PGADMIN_CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL=40
```

However the `PGADMIN_CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable doesn't seem to have any effect. When I start the container with `docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml up` and open the pgadmin page in my browser (http://localhost:5050/) I get all loggings from the pgadmin service.

Can anybody help to increase the loglevel to only showing `ERROR` and above? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think the excess logs are coming from `gunicorn` and not `pgadmin` itself.

To limit them you could add the following to the env file and docker compose itself according to your setup.

```
# in your env file
GUNICORN_ACCESS_LOGFILE="/dev/null"
```

```yaml
# your yaml file
GUNICORN_ACCESS_LOGFILE=${GUNICORN_ACCESS_LOGFILE}
```

This comment on a github issue that might help shed more light

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8578#issuecomment-945228061